# Is it OK settings location.href to force routing on the server-side?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, react-router-v4

I'm working on a React web app with an Asp.Net Core + Typescript back-end. The routing is on the front-end, managed by the React-Router v4. Everything is working fine so far.

By the way, there are cases where I need (I want) to redirect the routing by the server instead to let it to the browser logic. For instance, I want to force the redirection to a certain page when a cookie is not present or expired.

As just for instance, if I use something like `<Redirect to="/reserved" />` the React.Router does its best: routes toward the "reserved" page, but that's not what I want. I need this path supplied to the server, i.e. kind of bypassing the front-end routing.

In such cases, the solution I found is to set the desired path as follows:

```
window.location.href = '/reserved';
```

That seems sending the new path request straight to the server with no (apparent) involvement with the React.Router. Apparently, everything works fine, as I expect.

The question is: is it a reliable way to achieve the desired behavior, or it looks much likely a hack (and I should avoid it)?

Comment: I am not sure about asp.net-core, but can you redirect on a server request instead? So you make a request to a server endpoint, with the path you want as part of the the data, and the server validates the path, before redirecting you to a new page. Are you talking about router guards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the context of a single-page application (SPA), regardless of the framework or technology you are using, setting `window.location` explicitly is a perfectly fine way to leave the routing control of the SPA and force the browser to make an actual HTTP request for that new route.

Doing so of course means that the whole page will unload, so when doing that, you are leaving your SPA. If that target URL then loads the same SPA again, this will usually be distracting to the user. That is why common SPA router implementations will intercept route changes and handle them through their own routing instead of having the browser make an actual request.

You should check your router’s documentation to see if you can add some router guards that allow you to verify things on load or on route changes, so you can navigate the user away to some forced location.

If that target URL is not part of the SPA, then of course setting `window.location` is perfectly fine. It’s certainly not a hack but rather just the proper way to change the location without going through the SPA’s router.

Comment: Well, I wasn't able to find an explicit mention of a similar case. I found some example that relies on the browser side checking. However, I don't like that much: just opening the browser's debugger is a pretty simple way to bypass the checking. The server way looks much more robust to me. The (few) cases where I need this behavior do not impact with the user attention: the user realizes is doing something exceptional.

Comment: @MarioVernari You should understand your SPA as a client for your server’s API. As such, you need to protect your API against improper use, regardless of who or what uses the API. The client application is just an interface to make it easier to use. So if users decide to break your client application and messing around with it, that shouldn’t be a big problem. If, by manipulating your application, they decide to cancel out some route guards which would have explained them why they couldn’t do something, then it’s their own loss for not having the UI properly explain it to them.

Comment: I agree with you, but don't you think a simple "if" on the client side would be a weak door to break? I want to place my critical "if"s on the server side. Even in case the user tries to shoot calls against the server (e.g. Postman) I want to be sure that the door can't be opened.

Comment: You will usually want to do both: Put it on the client so that the user gets immediate and nice feedback (or not even a way to do things they shouldn’t do); and put it on the server as well to actually secure your endpoints. This is just like input validation; that happens on both the client and on the server.